# materialize image without margin

Tags: css, materialize

I'm having an image inside a div. Underneath it is a margim. I tried with firebug to look at the div code and img, but I did not find anything declared with magin and padding.

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col s4">
          <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8380.jpg" alt=""/>             
       </div>
       <div class="col s4">
          <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8265.jpg" alt=""/>                </div>
       <div class="col s4">
          <img  class="responsive-img" src="imagem/IMG_8711.jpg" alt=""/>
       </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try `img {vertical-align: top;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there. Set `img {display:block;}`